# reactjs onclick function change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still working with my first react app, now I am trying to create sort option by pressing table header
so the problem is, I do not know how to change onClick function after I press button.

What do I want: 
if I press `<th>first name</th>` table should sort by name ASC, then if I press on it second time, table data should sort by DESC.

I really appreciate your help :)

```
class App extends Component{


  state = {
    carowner: [],
    owner:
    {

        first_name:'',
        last_name:'',
        phone:'',
        email:''
    },
    delowner:
    {
      owner_id:''
    }
  }
componentDidMount()
{
 this.getOwners();
}
getOwners = _ =>{
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/owners')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => this.setState({ carowner: response.data }))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
addOwner = _ =>
{
    const {owner} = this.state;
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/owners/add?first_name=${owner.first_name}&last_name=${owner.last_name}&phone=${owner.phone}&email=${owner.email}`)
    .then(this.getOwners)
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

delOwner = (evt,owner_id) =>
{
  fetch(`http://localhost:4000/owners/delete?owner_id=${owner_id}`)
  .then(this.getOwners)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

getOwnersByNameASC = _ =>{
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/owners/sort/bynameasc')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => this.setState({ carowner: response.data }))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))

}

getOwnersByNameDESC = _ =>{
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/owners/sort/bynamedesc')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => this.setState({ carowner: response.data }))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))

}

renderCarOwner = ({owner_id,first_name,last_name,phone,email}) => <tr key={owner_id}><td>{owner_id}</td><td>{first_name}</td><td>{last_name}</td><td>{phone}</td><td>{email}</td><td><button onClick={(evt) => {this.delOwner(evt,owner_id)}}>Delete</button></td></tr>
render()
{
  const {carowner,owner,delowner} = this.state;
return(
  <div className="centerblock">
  <div>
  <input value={owner.first_name} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, first_name: e.target.value}})}/>
    <input value={owner.last_name} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, last_name: e.target.value}})}/>
    <input value={owner.phone} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, phone: e.target.value}})}/>
    <input value={owner.email} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, email: e.target.value}})}/>
    <button onClick={this.addOwner}>Add owner</button>


  </div>

  <table >
  <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th onClick=/* - F() - */>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th> 
                </tr>
{carowner.map(this.renderCarOwner)}
</table>

  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What about using react-table? It will sort by default.

Comment: you need to send column name and current status like ASE and DESC, manage on your API end.return all data return as per your order.

Comment: @SanatGupta 
How to define them in API? 
app.get('/owners/sort/byasc', (req, res) => {
const srt_byasc = `SELECT * FROM carowner ORDER BY ${column} asc`
    con.query(srt_byasc, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            return res.json(
                {
                    data: results
                }
            );
        }
    });
});

Comment: @Sergey you are using node js for the backend API.?

Comment: @SanatGupta
yes, im tryin to define variables for query, but I have syntax error - 
{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object] asc' at line 1","sqlState":"42000","index":0,"sql":"SELECT * FROM carowner ORDER BY [object Object] asc"}

Comment: you need to send parameters from fronted to backend like this `GET=>` `Your API path/?order_by=field_name&order=ASE or DESC` or use `POST` method as well.